# How to convert excel data in June 30, 2018, Hour 14 format to 2018-04-02T00:00:00 need excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

HI I have excel field in given  June 30, 2018, Hour 14  format I need excel formulat to convert into 2018-04-02T00:00:00 format

Comment: Are you saying you have a cell containing the TEXT "June 30, 2018 Hour 14?  Is it just one cell or multiple?  In the case of multiple, when the day is a single digit like 5, is it 05 or 5,  when the hour is less than 10, does it have a proceeding 0?

Comment: so please clarify your question do you want to see `2018-06-30 14:00:00`?

Answer (score 0):

I use these as my sample data :

```
June 30, 2018, Hour 14
August 3, 2018, Hour 17
July 13, 2016, Hour 1
```

then in _ (cellNumber) enter _ (equations :

```
D1 | =FIND(", ",A1,1)
E1 | =FIND(", ",A1,D1+1)
F1 | =MID(A1,1,D1-1)
G1 | =VALUE(MID(A1,D1+2,4))
H1 | =VALUE(MID(A1,E1+7,2))
I1 | =FIND(" ",F1,1)
J1 | =VALUE(MID(F1,I1+1,2))
K1 | =MONTH(F1)
L1 | =TEXT(DATE(G1,K1,J1),"yyyy-mm-dd")
M1 | =TEXT(TIME(H1,0,0),"hh:mm:ss")
N1 | =L1&"T"&M1
```

Drag D1:N1 until D3:N3 . done.

+-----[edit]----+

Or if your already have the data in Excel recognizable date/time format, just r-click > format cell > Custom > yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss

Hope that helps. (: